# CSS Compilation error at @include exports('class-name')

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm using a `node-sass` command to do some compilation of individual SCSS modules within a UI library. Most of the time things work out fine or with some adjustments to the `@imports` of the modules, but I often see this error and cannot find a good explanation.

example command:

```sh
node-sass -i scss/components/alert-banner/module.scss -o css/components/alert-banner/ --importer=../node_modules/node-sass-tilde-importer
```

but occasionally I get:

```sh
{
  "status": 1,
  "file": "/Users/kehyde/Desktop/collab-ui/core/scss/components/alert-banner/alert-banner.scss",
  "line": 3,
  "column": 10,
  "message": "no mixin named exports",
  "formatted": "Error: no mixin named exports\n        
on line 3 of scss/components/alert-banner/alert-banner.scss\n        
from line 6 of scss/components/alert-banner/module.scss\n>> @include 
exports('md-alert-banner') {\n\n   ---------^\n"
}
```

This points to the line of code:

```
@include exports('md-alert-banner') {
  .#{$prefix}-alert-banner {
    position: relative;
    padding: $alert-banner__padding;
    text-align: center;
...
```

I've tried scrounging the message boards, but am led mainly to more specific issue pages or too broadly versed SCSS introductory content.

I feel this is more of a gap in my knowledge than a problem with the code, but I need some insight that I cannot find elsewhere.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure that there is imported file with `exports` mixin? `Error: no mixin named exports` sounds pretty specific.

Comment: Mark me down as a dingus. It is there, just hiding out inside a `functions.scss` deep in the dungeon.

Answer (score 0):

This is user oversight, the property I needed resided elsewhere in the library to be found.